# Re-reflecting in HUD optics

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Simple HUD optics design can be described with below image.

[image: hud sample]

(source : http://www.mikesflightdeck.com/hud/head_up_displays.html)

As you can see, if combiner and colimating lens(after fold mirror) aligned to the center, i think view point(eye pupil) can see colimating lens(after fold mirror) according to the re-reflecting rays by combiner(another expression mirror reflection).

[image: explain image]

Simple test with a couple Beam splitter as shown below image

[image: bs1]
[image: bs2]
[image: bs3]

As above, we can see colimating lens(small b.s) at the big b.s(combiner).

Here are my questions:

1. To avoid those problems, should the ray have to be tilt(combiner, source ray's incident angle) obliquely to avoid re-reflecting ray.
   I think using this solution is a normal way.  how can I remove above problem(re-reflecting ray) in HUD optics?
2. it just idea, can I solve the problem with using polarization?(PBS or wave-plate)

---

Additional Example

i think it seems to look like this

[image]
<- like this

[image]
<- not like this

Comment: What's wrong with apertures and baffles?

Comment: @CuriousOne Case by my test, aperture is 10mm(no stop just B.S size)and no baffle(if using baffles, also seem together)